# Using textscan in Matlab to handle data not properly formatted data

Tags: matlab, textscan

I'm using `textscan` to import data.  I can get to it successfully import properly formatted data.  I can't get it to properly handle data that isn't properly formatted.  Below is the format of the data.

```
JeB2021Da 12-13 and stuff, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 99, 0, 0, 0, 
JoB2021Ha 12-13 and stuff, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 99, 2, 1, 0, 
JoP2021Co 12-13 and stuff, not enough samples
MaA2021Be 12-13 and stuff, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 99, 1, 0, 0, 
MaA2021Ma 12-13 and stuff, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 99, 1, 0, 0,
```

How would I handle the data that is, `not enough samples`?  Because currently the data structures don't line up.  The data structures that are being produced are `17 x 1` and `16 x 14`.  I'd like to import the string as it is in the data.  So `not enough samples` would be imported.  Below is the code that I'm using.

```
fid = fopen('./file.txt','r');
fmt = ['%s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d'];
d = textscan(fid, fmt, 'CollectOutput', 1,'Delimiter',',','headerLines', 1, 'EmptyValue', 0);
```

I'm trying to handle it with the `EmptyValue` flag but it's not working.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you mean by *I'd like to import the string as it is in the data*, or more exactly where you would like to have that string stored.

But about just reading your data as a whole you can use the 'TreatAsEmpty' argument:

```
d = textscan(fid, fmt, 'CollectOutput', 1,'Delimiter',',','headerLines', 1,'TreatAsEmpty','not enough samples');
```

Then you can modify the input further by looking for the rows in the imported data array that solely consist of zeros.